# How to display button with href tag using html5 in between php tags?

Tags: php, html

This is the code I am using to display certain data from mysql database in a template like panel. I want to know how can i display a button with href using html5 for every template.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
 echo '<div class="fetch">';
 echo "<p>".$result['FIRST_NAME']." ".$result['LAST_NAME']."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$result['QUALIFICATION']."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$result['Specialization']."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$result['Adress1']." ".$result['Adress2']."</p>";
 echo "<p>"."<b>Consultation Fee-</b>"." ".$result['Consultation_Fee']."  
 </p>";
 echo "<p>"."<b>Experience-</b>"." ".$result['Experience']."years"."</p>";

 echo '</div>';
```

Comment: `<button>` doesn't do anything without either being in a `<form>` or having a script attached. If you're trying to make a button that goes to a page ('with an href'), then just add another line that starts with echo and has an `<a>` tag in it. You can use CSS to make the `<a>` look just like a button.

Comment: Does this work? <a href="abc.php" class="slider-btn">Book Appointment</a>

Comment: I don't see why not.  Just make it look like the other lines up there where it is being `echo`ed and wrapped in quotes. Should be fine.

Comment: <a href="abc.php" class="slider-btn">Book Appointment</a> does not work.....   echo "<a href=login.php class=btn>Book Appointment</a>";  this will work...

Comment: You need quotes around you attribute values (login.php and btn). They can be single quotes so they don't get mixed up with the double quotes around the whole string.

Comment: double quotes do not work. But it works without any quotes and also with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

The plain HTML way is to put it in a `<form>` wherein you specify the desired target URL in the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

If necessary, set CSS `display: inline;` on the form to keep it in the flow with the surrounding text.

### CSS

If CSS is allowed, simply use an `<a>` which you style to look like a button using among others the [`appearance`][1] property ([only Internet Explorer support is currently (July 2015) still poor][2]).

```css
a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;

  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="button">Go to Google</a>
```

Or pick one of those many CSS libraries like [Bootstrap][3].

### JavaScript

If JavaScript is allowed, set the `window.location.href`.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well I knew how to create button in a form but not between php tags which I have answered in the comments.

Comment: you wamnt php tags just put the php tag in values of button it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```css
.btn {
            background: #3498db;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
            -webkit-border-radius: 28;
            -moz-border-radius: 28;
            border-radius: 28px;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<a href='your-link' class='btn'>Button</a>
```